# Make router use Dns Server of PC inside Lan

Tags: networking, dns, router

I am connected to internet via a TP-Link router. Router uses DNS servers provided by ISP. I have set up bind DNS server inside my PC and I want router to use DNS server on my PC instead of ISP's.

When I provide my IP (192.168.0.105) on preferred DNS server settings of router, I think router searches for this IP outside the LAN. Is it true? And if it is, what is the way redirect DNS queries to my PC?

Comment: My ISP's DNS IP is 120.138.96.18 which is set by default in router. When I change it to 192.168.0.105 (my lan PC ip address), is router intelligent enough to interpret that former is external ip address and latter is internal IP address?

Comment: Ok I got it. Router is providing correct DNS servers to the PC inside lan. So I think I have problems in bind configuration. Thanks for help.

Comment: You're welcome.  I basically condensed my comments into one answer below, feel free to upvote and accept.

Comment: Close voters: This question is about using a DNS server *running on Ubuntu* and is thus on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to actually confirm your assumption that the router is looking outside the LAN for the DNS server.  Confirming what you think here is tricky.  When you don't have a router you can do a full packet trace on, it's nigh impossible.

Effectively, though, your router is only getting those DNS servers so it can then later provide them to the machines inside via DHCP.  This is because for the most part DNS lookups occur at the *endpoint client/machine/workstation* level, not the router unless your router has a DNS forwarder which forwards DNS lookups outbound.  As such, the computers themselves will rely on the IP address as given.  The router is smart enough to know that the IP address is in the internal LAN subnet (there's programmed logic to know what the RFC-dicated private network ranges are instead of public and bogons), and will send it to that internal instead of externally to the Internet.  However, the IP destination for the DNS packet is determined for the most part at the endpoint machines internally instead of the router.

You should be able to alter the DHCP settings at the router so the machines connected to the router will automatically get the DNS server entry for the internal machine instead of the ISP servers.  From there, you should be able to test if your internal DNS is working as it should be.  It never hurts to keep the ISP (or if you're paranoid, Google) DNS servers as backups on the endpoint machines in case your bind server doesn't work.

Comment: I know this is a mini wall of text, sorry.